# Android image view matrix scale + translate

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, transformation

I am trying to manually get an image inside an imageview centered and fitting the screen. I need to do it with a matrix (I will later dynamically change the matrix transformation).

Problem is I can't get the image centered in the view (scale is appropriate). Here is the code:

```
// Compute the scale to choose (this works)
float scaleX = (float) displayWidth / (float) imageWidth;
float scaleY = (float) displayHeight / (float) imageHeight;
float minScale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);

// tx, ty should be the translation to take the image back to the screen center
float tx = Math.max(0, 
        0.5f * ((float) displayWidth - (minScale * imageWidth)));
float ty = Math.max(0, 
        0.5f * ((float) displayHeight - (minScale * imageHeight)));

// Compute the matrix
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.reset();

// Middle of the image should be the scale pivot
m.postScale(minScale, imageWidth/2, imageHeight/2);

// Translate
m.postTranslate(tx, ty);

imageView.setImageMatrix(m);
```

The above code works if I don't center the scale on the image center (but I will need to do it later so I need to figure out the formula now).

I thought doing the following would correct the issue, but the image is still offset (towards bottom and right).

```
tx += 0.5*imageWidth*minScale;
ty += 0.5*imageHeight*minScale;
```

Some values I have: 
- image: 200x133
- display: 800x480
- minScale: 2.4
- final top-left corner of the image: 100, 67 (should be 17, 0)

Comment: Hello, I am having the same kind of requirement. can you please share me the sample here. That would save my time.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

There's a convenient method called [Matrix.setRectToRect(RectF, RectF, ScaleToFit)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setRectToRect(android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.RectF,%20android.graphics.Matrix.ScaleToFit)) to help you here.

```
Matrix m = imageView.getImageMatrix();
RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
m.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
imageView.setImageMatrix(m);
```

That should set the matrix `m` to have combo of scaling and translate values that is needed to show the drawable centered and fit within the ImageView widget.

Comment: Thanks, I had solved the problem in the meantime by a combination of matrices. +1 for making me notice that useful function.

Comment: Care to share your solution?  I have a corner case where a combination of matrices could prove useful.

Comment: @joakime image doesn't show. Then, when I tap the image once, it will show but not centered and fitted against its view. I am using TouchImageView (source code here https://github.com/gabu/AndroidSDK-RecipeBook/blob/master/Recipe060/src/com/example/android/recipe060/TouchImageView.java)

Comment: @joakime, what do you replace "imageWidth" and "imageHeight" with (line 2 in your comment above)? I'm having the same exact problem right now but I'm stuck on this part. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Careful with the above, getImageMatrix() docs state "Do not change this matrix in place. If you want a different matrix applied to the drawable, be sure to call setImageMatrix()". However setImageMatrix() does a check and will not invalidate the view if the local matrix, mMatrix.equals(the matrix passed in). Hence I would recommend: Matrix m = new Matrix(); m.reset(); over getImageMatrix() in this instance.

Comment: hey how can i use this in scalling bitmap draw in center of canvas on surfaceview

Comment: how can i use scaletofit after image rotation? i have tried your code but it removes my rotation effect

Comment: Very useful for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I solved my problem using matrices (requested by joakime in the other answer):

```
private void setImageTransformation(float tx, float ty, float scale) {
    savedMatrix.reset();
    savedMatrix.postTranslate(-imageWidth / 2f, -imageHeight / 2f);
    savedMatrix.postScale(scale, scale);
    savedMatrix.postTranslate(tx, ty);
    imageView.setImageMatrix(savedMatrix);
}

public void resetImageMatrix() {
    if (!isImageLoaded()) return;

    imageWidth = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    imageHeight = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

    float scaleX = (float) displayWidth / (float) imageWidth;
    float scaleY = (float) displayHeight / (float) imageHeight;
    minScale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    maxScale = 2.5f * minScale;

    initialTranslation.set(
              Math.max(0, 
                minScale * imageWidth / 2f 
                + 0.5f * (displayWidth - (minScale * imageWidth))), 
              Math.max(0, 
                minScale * imageHeight / 2f
                + 0.5f * (displayHeight - (minScale * imageHeight))));

    currentScale = minScale;
    currentTranslation.set(initialTranslation);
    initialImageRect.set(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

    setImageTransformation(initialTranslation.x, initialTranslation.y, 
                minScale);
}
```

I am cheating here a bit because the pinch is not really centered between the user fingers, which is acceptable in my case.

Comment: what is initialTranslation, savedMatrix, displayWidth, displayHeight?

Comment: `initialTranslation` and `savedMatrix` are just reused `Matrix` instances. The code doesn't depend on their state because it entirely resets it before reading. `displayWidth/Height` are the dimensions of the target box into which the image must be placed.

Answer (score 3):

Or using

```
    m.postScale(minScale, minScale); //keep aspect ratio

    float tx = (getWidth() - bitmap1.getWidth()* scale) * 0.5f ;
    float ty = (getHeight() - bitmap1.getHeight()* scale) * 0.5f ;

    matrix.postTranslate(tx, ty );
```

where getWidth is the width of your imageView.
Works perfectly for me

Answer (score 1):

Hey I was having the same issue, and you were oh so close! It was an order of operations issue, at least for me.  The following worked for me:

```
tx = (width - imgWidth) * 0.5f * scale;
```