# how to scale a image to imageview in onCreate when i need to use scaleType matrix

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, zooming, scale

I'm trying to create a `ImageView` with zoom functions. 
I got the zoom function ready, but now I want the image to scale to the `ImageView`
when starting the `Activity`. Normally I would use the `ScaleType` in the xml layout, 
but it needs to be `Matrix` for the zoom function. How can I do this?

I tried the solution from this question: [Android image view matrix scale + translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075363/android-image-view-matrix-scale-translate)

```
Matrix m = imageView.getImageMatrix();
RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight());
m.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
imageView.setImageMatrix(m);
```

But the problem is I can't use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` because its to early (it only returns 0). Is there a work around? Or how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to a add an observer to the `ImageView`, that will be called when the object is layouted:

```
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
       int width = imageView.getWidth();
       int height = imageView.getHeight();
       // do your stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with matrix, zoom and imageview and the easiest solution I found is to render the image twice, one with scaleType fitcenter and Matrix.

After many (really many..) tempts with setRectToRect and the solution mentioned before (and so on..), I finally find a solution (at least for my case, similar to the post):

In the imageview in your activity xml set fitcenter:

```
    <ImageView
     ...
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Then in your java file define a init function on focus changed

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        init();
    }
}

private void init() {
    maxZoom = 10;
    minZoom = 1f;
    height = viewHeight;
    width = viewWidth;
    **Matrix m = imageSWT.getImageMatrix();
    imageSWT.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
    matrix.set(m);**

}
```

So I'm using the property of fitcenter and then I get his matrix, after that I switch to Matrix mode (for the zoom functionality) and I save the fitcentered-matrix into the matrix-zoom object for keeping the changes when the zoom is used.

I hope this solution could help someone ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to be sure of a views width and height is to subclass the view and override `onSizeChanged()` and use the given width/height or `onLayout()` and used `getMeasuredHeight()` and `getMeasuredWidth()`.

This means you're matrix won't be setup until way after `onCreate()` (until the view is about to be rendered for the first time), but at least the code you've posted could go entirely into the subclassed view.