# ImageView display region of an image

Tags: android, imageview

Is there a way in Android to show just an specific region of an image in an ImageView without preprocessing the bitmap? For instance using any of the available ScaleType (ie: MATRIX)?

Comment: Yeah, it is possible. Just create correct matrix to translate and scale bitmap. [An example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075363/android-image-view-matrix-scale-translate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps you, it contains the different ScaleTypes: http://etcodehome.blogspot.com.es/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html

Comment: thanks, apparently ScaleType.MATRIX setting a fix width and height for the ImageView does the job :)