# Fit to Android Imageview Matrix Center of Screen

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, center

Hello Im using a function for fit to screen on this topic [Android image view matrix scale + translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075363/android-image-view-matrix-scale-translate)

```
float imageWidth = imageDetail.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    float imageHeight = imageDetail.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
    RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageDetail.getWidth(),
            imageDetail.getHeight());
    matrix.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    imageDetail.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    imageDetail.invalidate();
```

It works effectively but not the first time. When I start the application It doesnt work. Image doesnt show. When I m tap It works. What Im do wrong?  Thanks for any advice

Comment: why not to use proper scaleType of ImageView?

Comment: I have to use matrix scaleType I cannot change it

Comment: use ImageView.ScaleType = FIT_CENTER and switch to MATRIX when you really need it

Answer (score 4):

Hi you should place your code in onWindowFocusChanged method.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    float imageWidth = image.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    float imageHeight = image.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
    RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
    RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0, image.getWidth(),
            image.getHeight());
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    image.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    image.invalidate();
}
```

Comment: this code remove my rotation...i dont know where i am wrong...please help me