# Can you scale an ImageView in code? Android

Tags: android, rotation, imageview, android-imageview

You can rotate an ImageView with

```
ImageView.setRotation(float rotation);
```

But can you scale?

EDIT:
Something like this...

```
ImageView icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++){
    Log.i("Rotate", "Rotating icon by " +    String.valueOf(i) + " degrees.");
    Log.i("Scale",   "Scaling icon by " + String.valueOf(i/90) + " degrees.");
    icon.setRotation(i); // rotate by i degrees (0 to 90)
    icon.setScale(i/90); // scale by i/90 (0 to 100%)
    try{Thread.sleep(5);}// sleep for a little bit
    catch(InterruptedException e){}
}
```

Should produce a result like... (without the translation)
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android image view matrix scale + translate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075363/android-image-view-matrix-scale-translate)

Answer (score 2):

You can scale the ImageView in code using

```
myImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType);
```

[ImageView.ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) is an enum with all the values.

Comment: See my edit, does this still apply to my situation? Thanks!