# Align image within imageView to bottom center

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-imageview, scaletype

I have a simple imageView and I want an image to be displayed in the center of the bottom. At the moment it is displayed in the bottom right corner.

```
<ImageView
      app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/simple_picture"
      android:id="@+id/picture"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_height="300dp"
      android:layout_width="330dp"
      android:scaleType="fitEnd"/>
```

is there any way to use scaleType for bottom **and** center?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android image view matrix scale + translate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075363/android-image-view-matrix-scale-translate)

Answer (score 2):

Add parent layout as Relative

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="350dp"


            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/oldman1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:gravity="bottom|center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_chat" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Add another view as parent

Answer (score 0):

You can take RelativeLayout as a parent layout and set in ImageView

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

try this ...

Answer (score 0):

Look at [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6172226/3926506) for similar question. I think, using `android:scaleType="matrix"` can resolve problem.

Answer (score 0):

If parent is linear layout then try :

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

If parent is relative layout then use :

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know from this question 5 years ago
But I wanted to help others
You do  [[ NOT NEED TO USE  scaleType ]] my friend

```
<RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="bottom|center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/myimageView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/MyImage" />
                </RelativeLayout>
```