# Android ImageView ScaleType bottom-left and top-right

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, scaletype

I'm trying to set some `ImageView's` `scaleType` so that they're rendered fit bottom-left and top-right (exactly the opposite corners than in `fitEnd` and `fitStart`), but been struggling quiet a bit time without success. I'm guessing I need to use `matrix` and create my own translation matrix as suggested on this thread:

[Android image view matrix scale + translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075363/android-image-view-matrix-scale-translate)

But can't figure out how may I apply it to my scenario. Anyone succeeded creating this 'custom' scaleTypes?